# Custom objects or Custom settings

Tags: custom-object, case, validation, customsetting

I would like to create a "spam list" with some of the case subjects. My first idea was to create a custom object, with a field (set) where I can add the different "spam" subjects, a couple of methods, one to add subjects (a button in the "case" detail) and other to remove subjects from a list. And then create a trigger, which before insert/update a case, check the list, and close the case if the current subject is already on the list.

I don't really need more than one object, so I have been reading that maybe it's better to use a custom setting. but I have no idea.

Which option would be better?

Comment: Look, Custom setting is for the limited data and we use it so that we don't need to Query data and it's cached as well;

Comment: How many subjects are you looking to blacklist? A `Validation Rule` might be better than any `Apex` solution here.

Comment: The idea is that this spamlist would be dynamic, I mean when we receive a new case, if we think it's a spam case, we include its subject in the list. So can I do that just with a Validation rule?

Comment: You might want to choose door #3 here, and look into implementing some machine learning algorithm to do this for you. Classifying subjects as spam/not-spam seems like it would be a good fit for machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to try to build a text field (i.e. `[Case].Case_Spam_Subects__c`) associated with a workflow rule. The workflow rule can trigger off a checkbox (i.e. `[Case].Mark_as_spam__c`) which will append the `[Case].Case_Spam_Subects__c` text field with the tagged Spam Case subject line. That way you don't need to update your list manually and you can use the `[Case].Mark_as_spam__c` to update a third boolean formula field (i.e. `[Case].Case_is_spam__c`) when `Contains([Case].Case_is_spam__c,Case.Subject)`.